# UXSE success rates

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Couple questions:

- Do we know if users are actually implementing answers/solutions they receive on UXSE?
- Do we know if the answer/solution actually worked for them?
- Should the users who provided the solution receive more reputation?

Comment: I think the closest we might get to this (at least on the very specific questions) is the accepted answer. I would love a way to follow up though.

Perhaps we could have a 'vote for follow up' feature on questions with accepted answers that would ping the 'asker' for a quick update after a certain number of votes.

Answer (score 1):

We do (very) occasionally get updates on questions, such as with [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15079/where-should-the-gui-light-source-come-from) where the poster came back to update question with what they have actually done.

However it is a common problem with forums and Q&A sites - people come along with a problem, then once they've had the answer they don't return.

StackExchange implemented the 'Accepted Answer' option as a way to both show the rest of the community that the answer is worked or is correct, and this also serves as a reputation boost the answerer.

Don't forget: [you can also hand out bounties to any answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) you find worked particularly well, and leave a comment about *why* the answer was appropriate. However the basic structure of this site is that if an answer works then you mark it as 'accepted' as a way of indicating to everyone that this is the correct answer.

Comment: Way to say the exact same thing I was saying with different words :P

Comment: @BenBrocka In before you though ;)

Answer (score 1):

We really can't know, in the general case, what worked for them or what people ended up going with. Generally upvotes for *useful to everyone* answers are enough to encourage good answers, but the accepted answer is sometimes a good proxy of "I did/will do this". If you decide to go with a solution or actually implement it, by all means leave a comment or even *give a bounty* to the answer that solved your problem.

Saying "I did this and it worked" as a little comment update is something I'd like to see more of, here's an example of a post doing so: [Where should the GUI light source come from?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/15079/7627) Not entirely sure I approve of it being added to the question body though.